# How do I use Dojo CDN + my.name.space.widget?

Tags: javascript, dojo, cdn

I want to use a CDN version of Dojo but I also want to use my collection of widgets in my own name space. How do I make the two play together?

Comment: Look up "cross-domain builds", should show you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `djConfig.baseUrl` too. The path of a module file is a combination of `djConfig.baseUrl` and module's path, if relative path is used in module path. See the example below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var djConfig = {
        baseUrl : "./",
        modulePaths : {"example" : "js/example"}
    };
</script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js 
"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        dojo.require("example.Sample");
        dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
            new example.Sample().sayHello();
        });
    })();
</script>
```

More details can be found at [`Cross-Domain Dojo`](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/cross-domain.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to config `djConfig.modulePaths` to point to your own modules. For exmaple:

> `modulePaths: {"com.yourdomain", "/js/com/yourdomain"}`

Comment: I did something like this: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js" type="text/javascript" djConfig="modulePaths: {'yoyo', '/js/yoyo'}"></script>
and I get the error: "invalid object initializer"?

Comment: You may need to put djConfig in the dojo script before
<script>
var djConfig = {modulePaths: {'yoyo', '/js/yoyo'}}
</script>
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4/dojo/dojo.js>

Comment: Still gives me "invalid object initializer" :(